# Phonagap and Cordova cli not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

My problem is a little bit weird, I installed phonegap and cordova cli step by step from the official tutorial and when I try to use phonegap create or something else on my Ubuntu 14.04, but the terminal is not write anything and then waiting for the next command.

Example#1:

```
expa@a42book:~$ cordova add platform android
expa@a42book:~$
```

Example#2:

```
expa@a42book:~$ cordova platform add android
expa@a42book:~$
```

I could only this way:

```
expa@a42book:~$ sudo nodejs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova platform add android
```

Someone has pulled into this problem and solved it?

Comment: Have you installed cordova globally using npm install -g cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my cordova install (and the command too), I followed this tutorial: http://jeffmcmahan.info/blog/installing-cordova-on-linux/ and it began to working.

> If that’s you, start by removing node.js as follows:
>
> $ sudo apt-get remove node
>
> Next, you’ll fix up up some Python
> dependencies:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
>
> And
> now we’ll add the proper repo for up-to-date releases of Node.js, and
> then we’ll run an update to grab the list of packages required to
> install node:
>
> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> We can now install Node.js itself:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install nodejs
>
> Finally, we install Cordova.
>
> $ sudo npm install -g cordova

Comment: add context, add significant parts of the tutorial which are part of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

Comment: The result is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Bad XML in your config.xml can also cause this, so if it just stops working out of the blue check your config.xml against an XML validator.